# Standard icon for UIBarButtonItem to display UIDocumentPicker?

Tags: ios, ios8

Is there any standard or recommended icon to use for a button that will bring up the  UIDocumentPickerViewController to import a document from another app?

Of the standard UIBarButtonItem icons, the most reasonable one to me would be "Organize", the one that looks like a folder.  But according to the iOS Human Interface Guidelines that icon's meaning is "Move or route an item to a destination within the app, such as a folder", which isn't really the same as importing a document from another app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import/add a document the most intuitive one would be the 'Add' button. Also, you can check out some other icons on the web and find one that fits your needs.

I don't recommend you to use the 'Organize' icon, because as the guidelines stated it's meaning is to "Move or route" items.